# json dump generating unnecessary curly braces

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

This question might have been asked many times but I am still unable to understand how to use json file. I use `json.dump(data, filename)`. While dumping I get unnecessary `{}` at the end of the file. So json.load(data) gives me below error.

```
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 1865 - line 1 column 1867 (char 1864 - 1866)
```

I read that there is no way to load a first or second dictionary. I have also read that there is a separater which can be used with json dump but I see no use here. Should I be using encoding, decoding here?

My json.dump file:

```
    {
    "deployCI2": ["094fd196-20f0-4e8d-b946-f74a56d2f319", "6a1ce382-98c6-4058-a929-95a7d2415fd0"], 
    "deployCI3": ["c8fff661-4482-4908-b722-4fac0227a8b0", "929cf1fa-3fa6-4f95-8464-d58e5490f4cf"],  
    "deployCI4": ["9f8ffa3c-460d-43a9-8113-58e891340e1b", "6e535e92-4da2-4228-a6ab-c8fc8d31adcd", "8e26a35e-7fb9-43b3-8026-d1283f7b678c", "f40e5c29-b4df-4cfb-9d7f-3bcc9c4dcf9f"], 
    "HeenaStackABC": [], "HeenaStackABC-DISK_VM1-mm55lkkvccej": ["cc2a89a2-3b27-4f88-af09-b3b0b1301056"]
    }{}
```

Edited: I think the code is doing something here.

```
with open('stackList.json', 'a') as f:
    for stack in stacks:
        try:
            hlist = hc.resources.list(stack_id=stack.id)
            vlist = [o.physical_resource_id for o in hlist if o.resource_type =='OS::Cinder::Volume']
            myDict[stack.stack_name] = vlist
        except heatclient.exc.HTTPBadRequest as e:
            pass
    json.dump(myDict,f)
```

I edited the code like below. I hope this is valid. It removed the last braces

```
    if len(myDict) != 0:
       json.dump(myDict, f)
```

Comment: The odds of a major python stdlib package like `json` being so broken that it generates invalid json are quite low actually. __Please post the minimal necessary code to reproduce the issue__ (chances are that while doing so you'll find the bug by yourself and find out it's somewhere in your own code).

Comment: Please check my edited question

Comment: "the minimal necessary code to reproduce the issue" means "all that's necessary to run the code on one own's computer without having to install your whole project".  No one can run your snippet on it's computer (`stacks` is not defined, and neither is `hc`).

Comment: The only way you could get the output you're seeing is if you were calling `json.dump` inside a loop, and trying to dump multiple objects to your file.  Since you haven't posted code that reproduces the problem we'll never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here :

```
with open('stackList.json', 'a') as f:
```

You're opening the file in 'append' mode, so each time the code is executed it appends the dump to your file. The result you complain about comes from this and `mydict` being empty on the second run.

You either have to open the file in "w" ("write") mode which will overwrite the existing content (you can eventually create a new dump file for each call) or switch to the ["jsonline" format](http://jsonlines.org/) (but your file will NOT be a valid json file anymore and any code reading it will have to know to parse it as jsonlines)

Comment: Ok, I get it. But with open('stackList.json', 'a') as f: inside the for and try is also not advisable right?

Comment: @Heenashree you should open and keep the file outside any loops in write mode, not open, write, close, within a loop

Comment: Fair enough. :)

Comment: @HeenashreeKhandelwal it's not even a problem of opening the file inside or outside the for loop - the 'a' mode means that each time your code is executed, it will __append__ to the existing file. If the file is initially empty or inexistant, after a first execution it will contain a single dump and will load correctly, but then any execution will append another dump at the end, making your file technically incorrect.